# How to reference the first node from the xml type provider

Tags: xml, f#, type-providers, f#-data

I cannot seem to be able to select only the first addresses postcode from the xml type provider.

The fragment below is a fragment from  larger XML document:

```
                <applicant>
                    <address>
                        <buildingno>8</buildingno>
                        <street1>Bob Way</street1>
                        <locality>Jones</locality>
                        <posttown>Somewhere</posttown>
                        <postcode>AB12 3QE</postcode>
                    </address>
                    <address>
                        <buildingno>9</buildingno>
                        <street1>SomeStreet</street1>
                        <posttown>Somewhere</posttown>
                        <postcode>AB13 4FE</postcode>
                    </address>
                </applicant>
```

I have loaded the documents in the type provider:

```
type XmlReqSample = XmlProvider<"C:\\Temp\\requests\\samples.xml", SampleIsList=true, Global=true>
```

Some of the requests only have one address, some have two or more which is why I tried loading a sample. I want to know how to select only the first addresses postcode:

```
// 'file' is a string of XML data
let doc = XmlReqSample.Parse(file)
let postCode = doc.Body.Applicant.Address.Value.Postcode.Value
```

However, I cannot select only the first postcode.

How do I select the first address and in particular the postcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#r "packages/FSharp.Data.2.2.3/lib/portable-net40+sl5+wp8+win8/FSharp.Data.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq"

open FSharp.Data

type XmlReqSample = XmlProvider<"sample.xml">
// file is a string of XML data
let applicant = XmlReqSample.Load(file)

let firstAddress =
  applicant.Addresses
   |> Array.tryFind (fun _ -> true)
```

> val firstAddess : Address option

Furthermore to get a postcode from an Address you can define a little function:

```
let getPostCode address =
  address |> Option.bind (fun (t:XmlReqSample.Address) -> Some t.Postcode)
```

and use like:

```
getPostCode firstAddress
```

> val it : string option = Some "AB12 3QE"

Comment: Thanks for your help. Some of the sample xml's are different. Not by much, but they are. I have 5000 of them that I need to process, in my sample list I had about 14 variants but one of my requests which was in the sample list was not conforming to what the type provider thought the document should look like, and therefore broke. I removed that request from the list to be processed and my original code worked. I don't think I can use `Addresses` if there is only one address node?

Comment: If your sample has multiple address as your xml above, then it will be inferred to be an array "Addresses"(plural). If you load data with only 1 address then you will have an array with 1 element.

Comment: so will have multiple Some will not, would be useful to find out how the type provider 'chooses' how to represent based on the list of samples I provide.

Comment: If 1 or more samples has multiple address items it becomes an enumerable property.